# Stable cohomology operation, natural homomorphism

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

How do I see that each $\Phi^q$ of a stable cohomology operation $\{\Phi^q\}$ is a natural homomorphism?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any (reduced) cohomology theory $\tilde H^*$, not necessarily ordinary, addition in 
$\tilde H^r(\Sigma X)$ is induced by the pinch map  $\Sigma X \to \Sigma X\ \vee \Sigma X$, using the natural isomorphism $\tilde H^r(\Sigma X \vee \Sigma X) \cong \tilde H^r(\Sigma X)\times \tilde H^r(\Sigma X)$ and functoriality.  Here $\Sigma$ is the suspension functor on based spaces.  From here, the conclusion follows by stability and naturality.